# Facebook Swift SDK - MessageDialog

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I'm trying to implement MessageDialog with Facebook Swift SDK.

The MessageDialog is presented in this way:

```
    let content = LinkShareContent(url: URL(string: "www.google.com")!)        
    let shareDialog = MessageDialog(content: content)
    shareDialog.completion = { result in

        print(result)

        switch result {
        case .success:
            print("A")
        case .failed:
            print("B")
        case .cancelled:
            print("C")
        }

    }

    do {
        try shareDialog.show()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Nothing happen, I also receive an error in the completion handler saying 'reserved'.

The documentation https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/blob/master/Sources/Share/ShareError.swift don't specify 'reserved' meaning.

Comment: Which sdk you are using?

Comment: version 4.16.0, installed using cocoapods

Comment: @Marco, have you figured the root cause of that `reserved` error? I'm having the same issue and I cannot find any solutions online.

Comment: me too, did you solve?

Answer (score 2):

I guess need implement it like the following, it works for me.

```html
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKShareKit

//=========================

let content: FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
content.contentURL = URL(string: "http://google.com")!

let shareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
shareDialog.shareContent = content
shareDialog.mode = .native
shareDialog.delegate = self
shareDialog.show()

//MARK: FBSDKSharingDelegate
    func sharer(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didCompleteWithResults results: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
        print(results)
    }
    
    func sharer(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didFailWithError error: Error!) {
        print(error)
    }
    
    func sharerDidCancel(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!) {
        print("cancel..")
    }
```

Comment: If you're using the use_frameworks! flag, you must also add pod 'Bolts' before the FBSDKCoreKit dependency.

Comment: Can not assign to self.

Answer (score -1):

"Reserved" error message happens when you try the sharing feature on the simulator, where there is no Facebook apps).

If you run your code on a device, it should word.

Max

Comment: This is not true, on my real device with the Facebook app it gives the reserved error